# Copy a row of values from a 1D array that represents a three dimensional grid

Tags: c#, java, optimization, data-structures, voxels

So I have a 1D array representing a 3D grid of numbers which represents the game world, I access individual entries (X,Y,Z) like so:

```
array[x + width * (y + height * z)]
```

Is there a way I can copy out an entire row (for instance, all the Z values for (1,1)) without looping (I'm already looping through every entry. I want to save performance by checking for empty rows (all 0s) and skipping processing them)? I'd rather not use a jagged array if possible.

Comment: C# or Java or what? Android? You should know by now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure your data elements are arranged linearly as rows in memory:

`row|row|row`... etc.

You can then use the same sort of array access arithmetic mentioned in your question, to determine your index range for that row, let's call the range `n->m`, then do a fast block copy for elements `n->m` as per the following:

- `memcpy` - C/C++
- `Array.Copy` - C#
- `Arrays.copyOfRange` - Java, good for native types; loop copy may be better for objects.

each of which will take `n` and `m-n` as `start` and `size` parameters, respectively.

Most languages will have some sort of implementation of a block array copy which uses native code under the hood, i.e. which performs a *native copy*.